# Visiualize and analyze relations of classes in c++ project

Tags: c++, uml

which free tool to use for getting visualized representation classes in c++ project?

Comment: That depends on what output you are expecting. Real time graphing integrated into an editor, or some kind of permanent output?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cppdepend.com/

You can download a trial version.

Answer (score 2):

If it's documentation, you could try doxygen - http://www.doxygen.nl/

or are you after UML?

Comment: No, not doxygen. Actually I want to investigate C++ project and I would like to parse classes with some tool to see visualized view of relationships.

Comment: you can combine doxygen with dot to generate graphs for "visualising" your code..